# How can I use C# style enumerations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumeration, language-construct

I just want to know the best way to emulate a C# style enumeration in Ruby.

Comment: Which specific features are you looking for? You could just put some symbols in an array...

Comment: Specifically, I would like to be able to perform logical tests against the set of values given some variable.  Example would be the state of a window: "minimized, maximized, closed, open".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Specifically, I would like to be able to perform logical tests against the set of values given some variable. Example would be the state of a window: "minimized, maximized, closed, open"

If you need the enumerations to map to values (eg, you need minimized to equal 0, maximised to equal 100, etc) I'd use a hash of symbols to values, like this:

```
WINDOW_STATES = { :minimized => 0, :maximized => 100 }.freeze
```

The freeze (like nate says) stops you from breaking things in future by accident.
You can check if something is valid by doing this

```
WINDOW_STATES.keys.include?(window_state)
```

Alternatively, if you don't need any values, and just need to check 'membership' then an array is fine

```
WINDOW_STATES = [:minimized, :maximized].freeze
```

Use it like this

```
WINDOW_STATES.include?(window_state)
```

If your keys are going to be strings (like for example a 'state' field in a RoR app), then you can use an array of strings. I do this ALL THE TIME in many of our rails apps.

```
WINDOW_STATES = %w(minimized maximized open closed).freeze
```

This is pretty much what rails `validates_inclusion_of` validator is purpose built for :-)

#### Personal Note:

I don't like typing include? all the time, so I have this (it's only complicated because of the .in?(1, 2, 3) case:

```
class Object

    # Lets us write array.include?(x) the other way round
    # Also accepts multiple args, so we can do 2.in?( 1,2,3 ) without bothering with arrays
    def in?( *args )
        # if we have 1 arg, and it is a collection, act as if it were passed as a single value, UNLESS we are an array ourselves.
        # The mismatch between checking for respond_to on the args vs checking for self.kind_of?Array is deliberate, otherwise
        # arrays of strings break and ranges don't work right
        args.length == 1 && args.first.respond_to?(:include?) && !self.kind_of?(Array) ?
            args.first.include?( self ) :
            args.include?( self )
        end
    end
end
```

This lets you type

```
window_state.in? WINDOW_STATES
```

Comment: Note: Adding instance methods to Object can be dangerous -- it's a little like adding stuff to the global namespace. Go down the Object#in? road with great caution.

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite the same, but I'll often build a hash for this kind of thing:

```
STATES = {:open => 1, :closed => 2, :max => 3, :min => 4}.freeze()
```

Freezing the hash keeps me from accidentally modifying its contents.

Moreover, if you want to raise an error when accessing something that doesn't exist, you can use a defualt Proc to do this:

```
STATES = Hash.new { |hash, key| raise NameError, "#{key} is not allowed" }
STATES.merge!({:open => 1, :closed => 2, :max => 3, :min => 4}).freeze()

STATES[:other] # raises NameError
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Ruby supports true enums -- though, there are still solutions available.

[Enumerations and Ruby](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/enumerations-and-ruby/)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to define an Enum in ruby to use a class with constant variables.

```
class WindowState
  Open = 1
  Closed = 2
  Max = 3
  Min = 4
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a class or hash as others have said will work. However, the Ruby thing to do is to use [symbols](http://www.rubytips.org/2008/01/26/what-is-a-ruby-symbol-symbols-explained/). Symbols in Ruby start with a colon and look like this:

```
greetingtype = :hello
```

They are kind of like objects that consist only of a name.