# What is the best way to handle constants in Ruby when using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, enumeration

I have some constants that represent the valid options in one of my model's fields. What's the best way to handle these constants in Ruby?

Comment: [This other question about Enumerations in Ruby seems to be very very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164714/how-can-i-use-c-style-enumerations-in-ruby)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use an array or hash for this purpose (in your environment.rb):

```
OPTIONS = ['one', 'two', 'three']
OPTIONS = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3}
```

or alternatively an enumeration class, which allows you to enumerate over your constants as well as the keys used to associate them:

```
class Enumeration
  def Enumeration.add_item(key,value)
    @hash ||= {}
    @hash[key]=value
  end

  def Enumeration.const_missing(key)
    @hash[key]
  end   

  def Enumeration.each
    @hash.each {|key,value| yield(key,value)}
  end

  def Enumeration.values
    @hash.values || []
  end

  def Enumeration.keys
    @hash.keys || []
  end

  def Enumeration.[](key)
    @hash[key]
  end
end
```

which you can then derive from:

```
class Values < Enumeration
  self.add_item(:RED, '#f00')
  self.add_item(:GREEN, '#0f0')
  self.add_item(:BLUE, '#00f')
end
```

and use like this:

```
Values::RED    => '#f00'
Values::GREEN  => '#0f0'
Values::BLUE   => '#00f'

Values.keys    => [:RED, :GREEN, :BLUE]
Values.values  => ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f']
```

Comment: I decided to go with this solution. I have to say, it does just what I want and plays nicely with ActiveRecord. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 11):

I put them directly in the model class, like so:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  ACTIVE_STATUS = "active"
  INACTIVE_STATUS = "inactive"
  PENDING_STATUS = "pending"
end
```

Then, when using the model from another class, I reference the constants

```
@model.status = MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS
@model.save
```

Comment: That is a method not a class.  Need to use "class" instead of "def".

Answer (score 9):

If it is driving model behavior, then the constants should be part of the model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  ONE = 1
  TWO = 2

  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => [ONE, TWO]
end
```

This will allow you to use the built-in Rails functionality:

```
>> m=Model.new
=> #<Model id: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> m.valid?
=> false
>> m.value = 1
=> 1
>> m.valid?
=> true
```

Alternatively, if your database supports enumerations, then you can use something like the [Enum Column](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/Enum+Column+in+MySql) plugin.

Answer (score 8):

Rails 4.1 added [support for ActiveRecord enums](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums).

Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

conversation.archived!
conversation.active? # => false
conversation.status  # => "archived"

Conversation.archived # => Relation for all archived Conversations
```

See [its documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for a detailed write up.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Be ready to get exceptions when you try to assign some value that is not in the list to the status field, and be ready to get name conflicts if you add another enum field with [:active] value.

Rails implementation of this feature really awkward.

Comment: i have made a gem for validating enums inclusion https://github.com/CristiRazvi/enum_attributes_validation

Answer (score 5):

You can also use it within your model inside a hash like this:

```
class MyModel

  SOME_ATTR_OPTIONS = {
    :first_option => 1,
    :second_option => 2, 
    :third_option => 3
  }
end
```

And use it like this:

```
if x == MyModel::SOME_ATTR_OPTIONS[:first_option]
  do this
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
It was an inspiration to group symbols in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also group constants into subjects, using a module --

```
class Runner < ApplicationRecord
    module RUN_TYPES
        SYNC = 0
        ASYNC = 1
    end
end
```

And then have,

```
> Runner::RUN_TYPES::SYNC
 => 0
> Runner::RUN_TYPES::ASYNC
 => 1
```