# How do i specify and validate an enum in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I currently have  a model Attend that will have a status column, and this status column will only have a few values for it.  STATUS_OPTIONS = {:yes, :no, :maybe}

1) I am not sure how i can validate this before a user inserts an Attend?  Basically an enum in java but how could i do this in rails?

Comment: mu and mike's answers are good - see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/265725/887124 , which gives some slightly different answers to a similar question.

Comment: Yeah, I actually use something more similar to the solution Bob provided: [gist](https://gist.github.com/1372650)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Create a globally accessible array of the options you want, then validate the value of your status column:

```
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATUS_OPTIONS = %w(yes no maybe)

  validates :status, :inclusion => {:in => STATUS_OPTIONS}

end
```

You could then access the possible statuses via `Attend::STATUS_OPTIONS`

Comment: Pre Rails 4.1 this is fine. In Rails 4.1+ use the built in enums: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums

Comment: Using "native" enums in rails 4.1 has the same drawbacks of using really native enums in postgresql. You need to take care of the actual order, you can't easily modify the enum once created etc. Moreover, with "native" rails enums, it's a broken feature, because on one side you write and read them as stings, but on the other side you need to query them as numbers. At least with postgresql's enums, everything out of the database will see strings.

Comment: After struggling for an hour trying to get enum work, this solution is far more interesting, and has no drawbacks - can't say the same for Enum.

Comment: Using `enum` makes database not so readable, you should consult your model to determine what does this `3` value means in database. So, I consider [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147002/52499) a better answer. After all, you can't have that much reputation for nothing :D

Answer (score 101):

Now that [`Rails 4.1`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums) includes enums you can do the following:

```ruby
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum size: [:yes, :no, :maybe]

  validates :size, inclusion: { in: sizes.keys }
end
```

Which then provides you with a scope (ie: `Attend.yes`, `Attend.no`, `Attend.maybe`), a checker method to see if certain status is set (ie: `#yes?`, `#no?`, `#maybe?`), along with attribute setter methods (ie: `#yes!`, `#no!`, `#maybe!`).

[Rails Docs on enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: From what I'm reading rails current implementation of enums are for internal values and not for exposing to users as the question asked (which I think is a shame). I'm getting this from the following thread from February 14. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971

Comment: Just a quick note, you have to define enums before the validation line.

Answer (score 17):

This is how I implement in my Rails 4 project.

```
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum size: [:yes, :no, :maybe]
    validates :size, inclusion: { in: Attend.sizes.keys }
end
```

Attend.sizes gives you the mapping.

```
Attend.sizes # {"yes" => 0, "no" => 1, "maybe" => 2}
```

[See more in Rails doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: Essentially the same comment as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146965/how-do-i-specify-and-validate-an-enum-in-rails/8147002#comment42094863_26365696), but this won't work, because enum attributes will throw a InvalidArgument exception on invalid values, before the validation is called. More on that here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971

Comment: @Koen. is right I tried this solution and ended up with the `ArgumentError` regardless.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a string column for the status and then the [`:inclusion` option for `validates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) to make sure you only get what you're expecting:

```
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :size, :inclusion => { :in => %w{yes no maybe} }
    #...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Rails 7.1+

After [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49100) you don't need some hacks. If you want the enum value to be validated before saving, use the option `:validate`:

```rb
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  enum :status, %i[active archived], validate: true
end

conversation = Conversation.new

conversation.status = :unknown
conversation.valid? # => false

conversation.status = nil
conversation.valid? # => false

conversation.status = :active
conversation.valid? # => true
```

It is also possible to pass additional validation options:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  enum :status, %i[active archived], validate: { allow_nil: true }
end

conversation = Conversation.new

conversation.status = :unknown
conversation.valid? # => false

conversation.status = nil
conversation.valid? # => true

conversation.status = :active
conversation.valid? # => true
```

If not pass this option (or explicitly pass `validate: nil` or `validate: false`), validation doesn't invoke and `ArgumentError` raises in case of invalid value

---

#### Before Rails 7.1

Rails [automatically validate](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bb52c41dbfdf8d57b58f82319506446b70bca1b1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L166-L170) this value raising error

```rb
def assert_valid_value(value)
  unless value.blank? || mapping.has_key?(value) || mapping.has_value?(value)
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{value}' is not a valid #{name}"
  end
end
```

What you can is override this method with empty body

```rb
# config/initializers/enum_prevent_argument_error.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Enum
    class EnumType < Type::Value
      def assert_valid_value(_)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After that validation `validates :status, inclusion: { in: statuses.keys }` will work (without this monkey patch `ArgumentError` raises). Warning: If you apply this monkey patch, you should double check that all enums have this validation. If there is no validation and no check constraint, invalid values will be saved as is in the database and will be as `nil` attriubute in the AR model

Answer (score 4):

What we have started doing is defining our enum items within an array and then using that array for specifying the enum, validations, and using the values within the application.

```
STATUS_OPTIONS = [:yes, :no, :maybe]
enum status_option: STATUS_OPTIONS
validates :status_option, inclusion: { in: STATUS_OPTIONS.map(&:to_s) }
```

This way you can also use STATUS_OPTIONS later, like for creating a drop down lists. If you want to expose your values to the user you can always map like this:

```
STATUS_OPTIONS.map {|s| s.to_s.titleize }
```

Comment: Rails 5 will automatically generate the class level method .status_options: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @mechnicov's aswner, in case someone else doesn't know ruby very well:

In Rails 7.1 +, if you are defining enums in hash format:

```rb
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    enum meal_type: {
        breakfast: 0,
        lunch: 1,
        snack: 2,
        dinner: 3
    }
end
```

you will have to change it slightly to pass the `validate: true` option, namely, changing the colon (`:`) position and adding an additional comma (`,`):

```rb
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    enum :meal_type, {
        breakfast: 0,
        lunch: 1,
        snack: 2,
        dinner: 3
    }, validate: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For enums in ActiveModels you can use this gem [Enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)

Answer (score 0):

After some looking, I could not find a one-liner in model to help it happen. By now, Rails provides Enums, but not a comprehensive way to validate invalid values.

So, I opted for a composite solution: To add a validation in the controller, before setting the `strong_params`, and then by checking against the model.

So, in the model, I will create an attribute and a custom validation:

***attend.rb***

```
enum :status => { your set of values }
attr_accessor :invalid_status

validate :valid_status
#...
private
    def valid_status
        if self.invalid_status == true
            errors.add(:status, "is not valid")
        end
    end
```

Also, I will do a check against the parameters for invalid input and send the result (if necessary) to the model, so an error will be added to the object, thus making it invalid

***attends_controller.rb***

```
private
    def attend_params
        #modify strong_params to include the additional check
        if params[:attend][:status].in?(Attend.statuses.keys << nil) # to also allow nil input
            # Leave this as it was before the check
            params.require(:attend).permit(....) 
        else
            params[:attend][:invalid_status] = true
            # remove the 'status' attribute to avoid the exception and
            # inject the attribute to the params to force invalid instance
            params.require(:attend).permit(...., :invalid_status)
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

To define dynamic behavior you can use `in: :method_name` notation:

```
class Attend < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:yes, :no, :maybe]
  validates :status, inclusion: {in: :allowed_statuses}

  private

  # restricts status to be changed from :no to :yes
  def allowed_statuses
    min_status = Attend.statuses[status_was]
    Attend.statuses.select { |_, v| v >= min_status }.keys
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rescue_from ::ArgumentError`.

```
rescue_from ::ArgumentError do |_exception|
  render json: { message: _exception.message }, status: :bad_request
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to place another solution.

```rb
#lib/lib_enums.rb
module LibEnums
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
        validate do
        self.class::ENUMS.each do |e|
          if instance_variable_get("@not_valid_#{e}")
            errors.add(e.to_sym, "must be #{self.class.send("#{e}s").keys.join(' or ')}")
          end
        end
      end

        self::ENUMS.each do |e| 
          self.define_method("#{e}=") do |value|
            if !self.class.send("#{e}s").keys.include?(value)
              instance_variable_set("@not_valid_#{e}", true)
            else
              super value
            end
          end
        end
    end
end
```

```rb
#app/models/account.rb
require 'lib_enums'
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  ENUMS = %w(state kind meta_mode meta_margin_mode)
  include LibEnums
end
```