# Enum validation in Rails 4.2 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, enums

My User model looks similar to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum type: [:admin, :reviewer, :super_admin ]
  validates :type, presence: true
  validates :type, inclusion: { in: User.types.keys }
end
```

When I submit anything outside the enum values, the validation doesn't stop the code from running, and I get a 500 error as a response with the following error:

```
'something submitted' is not a valid type
```

If I submit a blank field, the validation works:

```
"type": [
    "can't be blank",
    "is not included in the list"
]
```

What am I doing wrong? My code looks identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875406/1629709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails `enum` doesn't have in-built validation.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971)

> The current focus of AR enums is to map a set of states (labels) to an
>   integer for performance reasons. Currently assigning a wrong state is
>   considered an application level error and not a user input error.
>   That's why you get an ArgumentError.

You still can set `nil` or an empty string to the `enum` attribute without raising an error.

Comment: Thanks. What would be considered best practice for this case? Having a user_types table and a User.type_id foreign key attribute?

Comment: @Vasile sorry but i cant' give you **the best suggestion**, i don't know what a task you tried to resolve. Give me a full picture =)

Comment: I've got three types of users, an admin can add a user through a submit form.  There's going to be a drop-down with the user type, but I just wanted to make sure it's validated server-side as well. It seems weird that you can't validate a value to be part of an array.

Comment: there is a gem that adds a validator over specified enum attributes. this will add active model error message over attributes instead of raising errors.

https://github.com/CristiRazvi/enum_attributes_validation