# How to use an enum in a validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with an enum like this:

```
enum health_company: {
    company_a: 0,
    company_b: 1,
    company_c: 2,
  }
```

and a validation that should allow health company "company_c" only if the job is of type "job_x":

`validates :health_company, exclusion: { in: %i(company_c) }, unless: proc{ employee.last_job.job_x? }`

This validation is not working. What's the error? Is it even possible to exclude certain values from an enum based on a condition?

Comment: Hey I don't know how to post a linked question, but perhaps [this question will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146965/how-do-i-specify-and-validate-an-enum-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `rescue_from ::ArgumentError` in controller.

```
rescue_from ::ArgumentError do |_exception|
  render json: { message: _exception.message }, status: :bad_request
end
```